# Compile and build with single command line Java (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, command-line, alias

Is there way to set up an alias in such a way so that I could enter the command, followed by the argument in a single line?

For example, instead of

```
javac Program.java && java Program
```

I would be able to go

```
newcommand Program.java //or "newcommand Program", whichever is easier
```

which would do the same commands as the line above.

Comment: From JDK 11 you can just use `java Program.java`
  https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An `alias` is not made to accept parameters, define a function like this:

```
jcar() { javac $1.java && java $1 ; }
```

Then use it:

```
jcar Program
```

*(`jcar` was intended as an acronym for java-compile-and-run)*

Comment: Where do you define the function? In .bashrc?

EDIT: Yes, that's where. I figured it out. I appreciate it!

Comment: add a semicolon, writing `jcar() { javac $1.java && java $1 ; }` if you want to just define it in the command line, not in a `.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: For me it didn't work at all without the semi-colon, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 14):

Since Java 11 you can use a single command

```
java example.java
```

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Linked: [How to compile and run in single command in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180304/how-to-compile-and-run-in-single-command-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to enrico.bacis' answer, i personally don't like to have Program.class files cluttering up my workspace if i'm just testing a program, so i'd do

`jcar() { javac $1.java && java $1 && rm $1.class}`

in addition, i found it helpful to trap `ctrl-c` so that even if i end the program halfway, it still removes the `.class`

```
jcar() {
trap "rm $1.class" SIGINT SIGTERM
javac $1.java
java $1
rm $1.class
}
```

Comment: That more like a "_jcarar_" -> _java-compile-and-run-and-remove_

Answer (score 3):

I like to pass the full Program.java filename as the input parameter, allowing easy autocompletion.

Here's an edited version of notcompletelyrational's script, which expects commands like `jcar Program.java` rather than `jcar Program`:

```
jcar() {
  f=$1
  f2=${f%.*}
  trap "rm $f2.class" SIGINT SIGTERM
  javac $1
  java $f2
  rm $f2.class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite solution looks like this:

```
function jcar { javac ${1%.*}.java && java ${1%.*}; }
```

It can handle various inputs, such as

```
jcar myfile
jcar myfile.
jcar myfile.java
jcar myfile.class
```

It lets you use Tab more quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to answer you giving a piece of Makefile, but it would not be generic enough. Whenever you want to compile a more complex program (let's say 2 files), you need to compile the second as well. It might be in a package, in which case what you're asking does not work any longer. Same thing if you have to handle libraries.

For all these reasons, I strongly advise you to choose a building utility of your choice, `make`, `scons`, `ant`, and let's mention it `maven`. I find the later way to complex for small projects. But `ant` is my best candidate for java programs. In the end, you can just `ant run` which will run your program and recompile it if needed. Have a look on the [hello world tutorial](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) with ant.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to enrico.bacis' and notcompletelyrational's answer, how to run it under a package and clean up the package compiled files:

`jcar() {
        javac -d . $1.java && java ${PWD##*/}.$1 && rm -rf ${PWD##*/}/
}`

By the way, this function should be added to ~/.bash_profile for Mac OS and ~/.bashrc for Linux, respectively.

To run it:

```
jcar ProgramName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile and run your Java program in 1 command, try this:

```
javac Driver.java ; java Driver
```

Where your file is called `Driver.java`.

This will compile the program, and then sequentially execute it.