# How to compile and run in single command in java

Tags: java, compilation, command

I want to compile and run in the single command line. 
Usually, we first compile and after the run?

```
javac example.java

java example
```

can I run this,

```
javac example.java && java example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function :

```
Myfunction() { javac $1.java && java $1 ; }
```

The use :

```
Myfunction example
```

This question is duplicated , please to search before posting 
See : [Compile and build with single command line Java (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825864/compile-and-build-with-single-command-line-java-linux)

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 11 you can use a single command

```
java example.java
```

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330